# I can't extrude an object around edges in Unity U modeller

Tags: unity-game-engine

First sorry for my English, i just started to learn it 1 year ago. I want to make a barrel in Unity U modeller(downloadable in asset store), so i have made a cilinder and divided it into 3 part vertically with the loop slice tool. When i try to extrude it around the selected edges in 360 degrees, that edge is stay static, where the colored scale icon is lying, but all edges are selected. I have tried to make it in a new project, but the same problem. Can anyone help me, please?

https://i.ibb.co/9ZLtGZw/image-2021-05-10-131701.png